# GWT (Google Web Toolkit) Slider for Touch Devices such as iOS, Android Tablets and so on

Tags: ipad, gwt, widget, slider, touch

we develop an application for a big swiss company. The application is developed using the Google Web Toolkit (GWT) and the main devices from which the application is accessed are iPads. Therefore, we try to find a Widget (also a proprietary framework is acceptable) which helps us to implement a slider which can be used on an iPad and whereby the widget incorporates with standard GWT widgets. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.m-gwt.com

Its an extension to gwt for mobile devices. It is still pre 1.0 but the 1.0 release is due in a few weeks and yes it contains a slider (but much more...)